# Programar función de matrices y vectores con numpy (spyder)

Tags: python, matrices

Tengo que programar una función `suma_a_cada_columna(mat, vec)` que dada
una matriz y un vector retorne la matriz que se obtiene sumando a
cada columna el vector.

El numero de filas de mat coincide con el tamaño de vec.

```
suma_a_cada_columna(np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [2, 1, 0]]), np.array([1, 2, 3]))
```

Resultado:

```
array([[1, 1, 1],[2, 3, 2],[5, 4, 3]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si existe una forma más directa/eficiente de hacerlo pero puedes transponer la matriz o el vector y usar la suma en el contexto de NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

def suma_a_cada_columna(matriz, vector):
    return (matriz.transpose() + vector).transpose()
```

De esta forma, si llamamos a la función:

```
suma_a_cada_columna(np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [2, 1, 0]]), np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

Obtenemos como salida:

```
numpy.array([[1 1 1]
            [2 3 2]  
            [5 4 3]])
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @FJSevilla, creo que tu respuesta me soluciona el problema.